# How to design a yes/no vote system with MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database-schema

I need to design the schema of my mongodb database and i want to choose the best schema. I have a **collection of item** (ITEMS), and **everyone can vote (yes or no) for any of theses items**.

one item can have many votes (around 10000 but can go up to 100000 and even more). Now where i must store the votes? inside the items like this :

```
ITEMS: {
  _id: int32, // id of the item
  ...
  vote_yes:[int32], // the ids of people who vote yes
  vote_no:[int32], // the ids of people who vote no
  ...
}
```

but this will make document in my items collection a little big (for exemple with 100 000 votes, one document can take around **500 kb**! but i don't know if this matter or not, and what are really the concequence). Or i can store the vote inside a different collection dedicated to vote (where i use it only for the vote, so the size don't really matter) :

```
VOTES: {
  _id: int32, // id of the item
  vote_yes:[int32], // the ids of people who vote yes
  vote_no:[int32], // the ids of people who vote no
}
```

but the problem is the filter ! **i need to retrieve document from the items** where **vote_yes not contain my ID and vote_no not contain my ID** and some additional filter dedicated to the items (like localization). i thing doing a join in mongodb will be painless and not very efficient

so it's where i m, what schema to choose? 
thanks by advance for you help !

Comment: 100,000 items will not nest very well. I would not recommend you store them in the schema. The consequence of nesting this is serialisation of the structure of the document, the size will be insignificant

Comment: As in mongodb, one document can take size upto 16mb, so you can store it within items &  there will be no problem in retrieving that data on your conditions. But still if you think, in future it make some problem, you can  use a log table & insert the duplicate copy of votes in that collection. Nesting is not problem in mobgodb, so you can nest as mongodb support, so you can continue with that.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to store the votes in separate documents in a separate collection.

The reason is that growing documents are problematic for MongoDB, because everytime a document grows to twice its inital size it needs to be moved to a different location in the database file. This slows down writes.

However, when you store votes separately, you can easily make other queries like finding a voting statistic of a specific users. It also gives you the option to store more meta-inforamtion with the votes, like the date the vote was made.

Example:

```
{
    item: [itemId],
    user: [userId],
    vote: [1 or -1],
    date: [ISODate]
}
```

As indexes I would recommend a compound index on `{ item:1, user:1}` with `unique:true` to prevent duplicate votes. This index will also speed up getting the vote-count for an item. An additional index on only `user` to quickly get the votes of specific users might also be useful.

The downside is that getting the vote-count for a specific question requires you to make a `.count` over the vote-collection. So you might consider to keep a copy of the current vote-count in the item-documents.

Comment: this is similar to likes on facebook. Good answer.

Comment: To consider, WiredTiger (default as of MongoDB 3.2) does not suffer from swiss cheese problems

Comment: Thanks philips. But in this way how select all the items with a price between 200 and 300 (for exemple) that the user xxx vote yes ?

Comment: @loki You didn't say you wanted to do anything like that. When this is a very common query, you could put the price in the vote-document. When it is not that common you might use an aggregation with [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup), but keep in mind that it removes the option to shard at least one of the collections. The last resort would be to simply do the join on the application level.

Comment: hmm yes i can add the price in the vote document, but in this way the schema must be not 1 document for 1 vote but 1 document for 1 item with inside all the votes made on this item ? i must also be able to retrieve all the items to with i didn't vote yet ...